# Reference variables by string in loop when normalising multiple variable names (assign and get do not seem to work)

Tags: r

I am trying to normalise column names for all data sets in the global environment. Since I am using a loop I would need to use strings to reference the data sets. Many similar examples suggest using either `get` or `assign` but neither seems to work in this case.

```
library(magrittr) #the piping operator
library(rattle) #normVarNames()

datanames <- names(which(sapply(.GlobalEnv, is.data.frame))) 

for(name in datanames){
    names(name) %<>% normVarNames()
}
```

Comment: Why are these data.frames not together in a list (over which you could easily iterate)? Forget the `assign`/`get` approach. It is extremely bad practice and not how you do this in R.

Comment: What do you mean about together in a list ? The names of the data.frames are under `datanames`

Comment: If you want to iterate over them, they are similar in some aspects. That means it is good practice to put them together into a list (when they are created) instead of having them free-floating in your global environment. Keep your global environment tidy!